# error : expected identifier or '(' in global variable

Tags: c, strtok

I got this errror during compile processing. 
I already saw this error in this site before, I think this error can occur when the ; or something are in wrong place. but I can't find.

[image: Screenshot]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX 80

typedef struct assemble
{
    int op;
    int ni;
    int xbpe;
    int addr;
}Assemble;


void get_token(char *bp);
int hTod(char *dp);
int bTod(char *dp);
void codeBreak(char *cp);
void result(int t);


Assemble asm;
int type;


int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  char buf[MAX];

    if( (fp = fopen("inst.txt","r")) == NULL ){
    fprintf(stderr, "file not found...\n"); exit(1);
    }
    while(fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),fp) != NULL){
         get_token(buf);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
 }

 void get_token(char *bp)
 {
    char    *cp;
    int i = 1;

    for(cp=strtok(bp, " \t\n"); cp != NULL; )
    {

        if( (*(cp+0) == '0') && (*(cp+1) == 'x') )
        {
        if( i == -1 )
            asm.addr = hTod(cp);
        if( i == 1)
                asm.op = hTod(cp);
        i *= -1;
        }
        else
        {
        codeBreak(cp);
    }

     cp = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
    }

result(type);
 }


 void codeBreak(char *cp)
 {

    if ( strlen(cp) == 2 )          // ni 판단
    {
    asm.ni = bTod(cp);
    }
    else if( strlen(cp) == 1 )
    {
       asm.xbpe = bTod(cp)*pow(2,3);    
       type = 1;
    }
    else if( strlen(cp) == 4 )
    {
    if( *(cp+3) == '1')     
    {
        asm.xbpe = bTod(cp);
        type = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        asm.xbpe = bTod(cp);
        type = 3;
    }
   }
 }

 void result(int t)
 {
    switch(t)
    {
     case 1 : printf("0x%x%x\n", (asm.op+asm.ni), asm.addr); break;
     case 2 : printf("0x%x%x%.5x\n", (asm.op+asm.ni), asm.xbpe, asm.addr); break;
     case 3 : printf("0x%x%x%.3x\n", (asm.op+asm.ni), asm.xbpe, asm.addr); break;
     default : break;
     }
   }


    /* Hex to decimal */
    int hTod(char *dp)
    {
        int i;
        int dec = 0; 

         for( i=2 ; i < strlen(dp) ; i++)
          {
            switch (*(dp+i))
             {
              case 'a' : *(dp+i) = 58; break;
              case 'b' : *(dp+i) = 59; break;
              case 'c' : *(dp+i) = 60; break;
              case 'd' : *(dp+i) = 61; break;
              case 'e' : *(dp+i) = 62; break;
              case 'f' : *(dp+i) = 63; break;
              }

          dec += (*(dp+i)-48) * pow( 16, (strlen(dp)-(i+1)));   

        } 
       return dec;  
      }

        /* binary to decimal*/
        int bTod(char *dp)
        {
            int i;
             int    dec = 0;

            for( i = 0; i < strlen(dp) ; i++)
            {
                dec += (*(dp+i)-48) * pow( 2, (strlen(dp) - (i+1)));    
             }
              return dec;
          }
```

Answer (score 4):

`asm` is a keyword. Instead of

```
Assemble asm;
```

use something different, such as:

```
Assemble asm1;
```

The problem reported by the compiler is different though. You seem to have used

```
ASSEMBLY asm;
```

in the code you compiled.

Comment: I didn't know about it. haha I watched it during 6 hours. Thanks! Thank you!

Comment: Alternatively, use one of the flags that tells gcc (or your compiler) to be more standards-compliant. (I think setting any non-gnu standard will do this, for example, with `-std=c11`)

Comment: `asm` is not a *standard* keyword, but treating it as one is a common extension.